# aleagpu - atomicCAS and __shfl_xor

Tags: aleagpu

I cannot find these two apis (atomicCAS and __shfl_xor) in the aleagpu framework. Is there a special problem using them or are they likely to be supported in the future ?

Comment: Perhaps they were overlooked? Have you contacted Alea?

Comment: yes  but the support page directed me to stackflow to ask questions using the aleagpu tag "Be part of the Alea GPU community and ask your questions on stackoverflow! Our community is constantly growing."

Comment: Oh ok. This seems to me to be more of a question for the devs than for the community though (I mean how are we to know if it will be added?)

Comment: Yes I agree. I have emailed their commercial support now. At least this might save someone else a mornings exploration.

Comment: Release 2.1 is available and it supports atomicCAS and __shfl_xor. There is an issue with atomicCAS on Linux though, which is going back to an issue of NVIDIA NVVM on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

We will support atomicCAS and __shfl_xor in the upcoming version 2.1 of Alea GPU, which will be released soon.

Comment: Release 2.1 is available and it supports atomicCAS and __shfl_xor as mentioned [here](https://twitter.com/EgloffDaniel/status/611530934207291392). There is an issue with atomicCAS on Linux though.